# The code owl carousel included in TYPO3 does not work

Tags: javascript, typo3, typo3-9.x

I have included this fragment html code into TYPO3.

```html
<!-- Owl Carousel-->
                  <div class="owl-carousel owl-carousel-classic" data-items="1" data-dots="true" data-nav="true" data-nav-class="[&quot;owl-prev mdi mdi-chevron-left&quot;, &quot;owl-next mdi mdi-chevron-right&quot;]" data-photo-swipe-gallery=""><a class="thumbnail-classic" data-photo-swipe-item="" data-size="770x510" href="fileadmin/intense/images/real-estate/single-property-page-01-770x510.jpg">
                      <figure><img width="770" height="510" src="fileadmin/intense/images/real-estate/single-property-page-01-770x510.jpg" alt=""/>
                      </figure></a><a class="thumbnail-classic" data-photo-swipe-item="" data-size="770x510" href="fileadmin/intense/images/real-estate/single-property-page-02-770x510.jpg">
                      <figure><img width="770" height="510" src="fileadmin/intense/images/real-estate/single-property-page-02-770x510.jpg" alt=""/>
                      </figure></a><a class="thumbnail-classic" data-photo-swipe-item="" data-size="770x510" href="fileadmin/intense/images/real-estate/single-property-page-03-770x510.jpg">
                      <figure><img width="770" height="510" src="fileadmin/intense/images/real-estate/single-property-page-03-770x510.jpg" alt=""/>
                      </figure></a><a class="thumbnail-classic" data-photo-swipe-item="" data-size="770x510" href="fileadmin/intense/images/real-estate/single-property-page-05-770x510.jpg">
                      <figure><img width="770" height="510" src="fileadmin/intense/images/real-estate/single-property-page-05-770x510.jpg" alt=""/>
                      </figure></a><a class="thumbnail-classic" data-photo-swipe-item="" data-size="770x510" href="fileadmin/intense/images/real-estate/single-property-page-06-770x510.jpg">
                      <figure><img width="770" height="510" src="fileadmin/intense/images/real-estate/single-property-page-06-770x510.jpg" alt=""/>
                      </figure></a><a class="thumbnail-classic" data-photo-swipe-item="" data-size="770x510" href="fileadmin/intense/images/real-estate/single-property-page-07-770x510.jpg">
                      <figure><img width="770" height="510" src="fileadmin/intense/images/real-estate/single-property-page-07-770x510.jpg" alt=""/>
                      </figure></a><a class="thumbnail-classic" data-photo-swipe-item="" data-size="770x510" href="fileadmin/intense/images/real-estate/single-property-page-08-770x510.jpg">
                      <figure><img width="770" height="510" src="fileadmin/intense/images/real-estate/single-property-page-08-770x510.jpg" alt=""/>
                      </figure></a>
                  </div>
```

Links to images are properly.

https://www.remax-prestige.pl/t3/fileadmin/intense/images/real-estate/single-property-page-02-770x510.jpg

What may be the problem? How can this be done? I plan to insert this images from the database.

Comment: Maybe you need to check the figure tag style first from the dev tools

Comment: How do you have included the above HTML code? as content elemnet type HTML? And have you include the CSS an JS files of owl?

Comment: I include the code in Content Element >> Type >> Special >> HTML. I have include also CSS and JS.